# Clear all controls / checkboxes without submit

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I clear all textboxes / uncheck checkboxes in my asp.net page without doing a form submit (don't want to trigger validation controls)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a simple HTML tag for that: `<input type="reset" value="Clear" />`

Make sure that any controls you want to clear are in the same form as the reset button.

Comment: voted up - but please be noted that RESET functionality resets the value of controls to original values set at the time of load. RESET does not mean CLEAR.

Comment: coincedentally, the page load values of all fields are blank. Thanks for pointing that out curious_geek.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var control in this.Controls)
{
    if (control is TextBox)
    {
        ((TextBox)control).Text = "";
    }
    if (control is CheckBox)
    {
        ((CheckBox)control).Checked = false;
    }
}
```

And here's a [recursive version](http://aspalliance.com/642_Control_Tree_Recursion) if you want to visit all controls..

Comment: this submits the form, hence triggers the validation controls; Need code that will not submit the form;

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can simply reload the page.

`Response.Redirect("thispage.aspx");`

Answer (score 0):

Please try if this works:

```
function reset(){
document.forms[0].reset();return false;}
```

Call this javascript function upon client click event of a button. or add it as attribute:

```
ResetButton.Attributes.Add("onClick", "document.forms[0].reset();return false;");
```

HTH